# Is a Mexican permanent visa the same as a national identity card?

Tags: esta, residency, identity-cards, japanese-citizens

I am trying to apply for ESTA. I am Japanese living in Mexico, with a permanent visa.

1. Is the permanent visa a *National identity card*?
2. If yes, there is no expiration date on the permanent visa. What should I put in the form? Would it be *0000*?

Answer (score 4):

The ESTA application is referring to national identity cards as [listed in this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_identity_card_policies_by_country), not visas.

More specifically, Mexico does not have a national identity card system, and your permanent visa for Mexico does not count as one.

Comment: A national ID card doesn't have to be mandatory to count as such. Mexico has a national ID card for citizens aged 4-17, the *cédula identitda personal*, which I, in that situation, would definitely have listed in the application.

Comment: @Coke They stopped issuing those in 2013.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. I guess existing ones are still valid though, as they're listed as passport exemptions for Mexico in TIMATIC (albeit simply referred to as national ID cards). What about the *cédula de identidad ciudadana* (which has greater height than width)?

Comment: @Coke as I understand it, Mexican law considers minors to be noncitizen nationals because they cannot vote.

Comment: Coke's "doesn't have to be mandatory" comment is correct, however.  What I *think* they're asking about is a non-passport citizenship document.  These are available in several countries, and they are mandatory or not to varying degrees.  Indeed, Coke has written many times on this site about his Swedish ID card, which, apparently, relatively few Swedes have.

Comment: @phoog "What I think they're asking about is a non-passport citizenship document" That is correct, which is also supported by the wording "national identity card for travel". MERCOSUR's national IDs for foreign residents are valid for travelling between the countries, and also for entering/exiting several of the member states to/from elsewhere (I'm honestly torn about whether I'd mention one of those). Otherwise, though, it's IDs tied to citizenship that can be used for travel.